# Debugging FPDF invalid call after upgrading laravel and PHP8

Tags: laravel, php-8, fpdi

I have a web app that used FPDI to create pdf files, using `laravel 5.7`, `setasign/fpdi-fpdf ^2.0` and `PHP 7.4`.
I recently upgraded to `laravel 9` (also upgrading respective dependencies) and  because the meta package was depcrecated, I now use `"setasign/fpdf": "^1.8", "setasign/fpdi": "^2.0"` as well as `PHP 8.0.26`

Now when trying to run my script I get the error `"FPDF Error: Invalid Call"` with the whole trace in the error handler, but I find this error message only semi informative.
Any ideas how I can debug this error?
Does FPDI have issues with PHP8? I didn't see any mention of that in the documentation.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From FPDF code, the error is shown when state == 1

[fpdf.php#L1458](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L1458)

```
protected function _out($s)
{
    // Add a line to the current page
    if($this->state==2)
        $this->pages[$this->page] .= $s."\n";
    elseif($this->state==0)
        $this->Error('No page has been added yet');
    elseif($this->state==1)
        $this->Error('Invalid call');
    elseif($this->state==3)
        $this->Error('The document is closed');
}
```

And state 1 is when the page ends

[fpdf.php#L1128](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L1128)

```
protected function _endpage()
{
    $this->state = 1;
}
```

Which happens when you close the document by calling `output()` (*and when you switch to the next page but that automatically opens the next page*).

So you might also have to read the new documentation of FPDF and adapt the code related to it.

Comment: Thanks, after trying to hard code a file to ```output()``` I finally caught the issue - I was using the FDPF class script "AlphaPDF" which appearantly doesn't work anymore, for some reason (some unclear compatibillity issue with PHP8 I guess)